# Looping through a dataframe (sorry) and checking if the current value exist in the previously looped values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looping through a dataframe (sorry, I know that's not ideal) and I wanted to check (at a certain point, for example i=n) if the current value on the column 'SKU', is present in the previous (n-1) values, so I tried:

```
if df['SKU'][i] not in df['SKU'][:i-1]:
```

but it's not working.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `df['SKU'].duplicated()`?

Comment: thanks for your comment, but checking if the column has duplicates is not the point of the loop, it's just a condition upon which to do different things

Comment: Yes but `for i in df['SKU'].duplicated(): if i do_something`?

Comment: use `.shift(-1)`?

Comment: Hi @DanailPetrov, could you elaborate please? Would that work for checking if the value at i is present at somepoint in the previous n-1 rows?

Comment: Check the solution I provided?

Comment: btw, if this condition you’re doing is within a row loop, you should use .index & .loc. My solution works if you’re not looping through..

Comment: [:i-1] isn't checking previous n rows, it's check ALL rows up to i-1. Is that what you want or do you want n=5 or n=3, which is previous 5 or 3 rows, respectively?

Comment: I want to check if the current value have been found before on the loop (so basically, if i=n, i want to check if the value at i exist in the previous n-1 values of the column

Comment: Ok, it's unclear why you need to introduce n if you are only comparing i to [0:i-1], but if you do need to check only a certain number of rows prior, that's a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df.SKU == df.SKU.shift()
```

Comment: Please include an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

By way of trial and error, I figured I just needed to use .values at the end of the comparison like so:

```
if df['SKU'][i] not in df['SKU'][:i-1].values:
```

Thanks!